# Vector of pointers throws error on push_back

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, data-structures, tree

Spiral/Zigzag level order traversal of binary tree. Initailize vector of pointers to traverse and pop from the front but don't know why its not working

[image: Spiral tree print]

Here is my code sample
**Code:**

```
void spiralPrint(Node *root)
        {
            if(root!=NULL)
            {
                vector<Node *> v;
                v.push_back(root);
                int j=1;
                while(v.empty() == false)
                {
                    int count = v.size();
                    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
                    {
                        if(*v.begin()->left != NULL)
                        {
                            v.push_back(*v.begin()->left);
                        }
                        if(*v.begin()->right != NULL)
                        {
                            v.push_back(*v.begin()->right);
                        }
                        v.erase(v.begin());
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Error:**

```
D:\c++\trees\binaryTree.cpp: In function 'void spiralPrint(Node)': 
D:\c++\trees\binaryTree.cpp:136:32: error: request for member 'left' in ' v.std::vector<_Tp,
    _Alloc>::begin<Node, std::allocator<Node> >().gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-><Node, std::vector<Node> >()', which is of pointer type 'Node' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?) 
        if(v.begin()->left != NULL) 
        ^~~~ 
        D:\c++\trees\binaryTree.cpp:138:45: error: request for member 'left' in ' v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<Node, std::allocator<Node> >().gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-><Node, std::vector<Node> >()', which is of pointer type 'Node' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
        v.push_back(v.begin()->left); 
        ^~~~ 
        D:\c++\trees\binaryTree.cpp:140:32: error: request for member 'right' in ' v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<Node, std::allocator<Node> >().gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-><Node, std::vector<Node> >()', which is of pointer type 'Node' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?) 
        if(v.begin()->right != NULL) 
        ^~~~~ 
        D:\c++\trees\binaryTree.cpp:142:45: error: request for member 'right' in ' v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<Node, std::allocator<Node> >().gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-><Node, std::vector<Node> >()', which is of pointer type 'Node' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
        v.push_back(*v.begin()->right);
```

Comment: Don't use `*` for checking `v.begin()->left != NULL` or  `v.begin()->right != NULL`

Comment: v.begin() would give pointer to the first memory block of vector. But we need the pointer that is stored at that first position of vector to move left-right of the tree..
@rootkonda

Comment: You are storing the address back to vector and `->` is used to access data at that address. Please read about how pointers work.

Comment: Please include definition for `Node`. See [mre].

Comment: *"v.begin() would give pointer to the first memory block of vector."* -- no, `v.begin()` gives an **iterator**, not a pointer. That iterator de-references to the pointer stored in the vector, which in turn gets de-referenced to your node. Perhaps you want to use `v.front()` instead of `v.begin()`? Or perhaps `(*v.begin())->left`? *(The code-to-text ratio of this question is rather high, so I have not read it carefully enough to know if that is an answer.)*

Comment: Also, please don't include loops that do nothing but make output when it's not relevant to the problem

Comment: Thanx @JaMiT. `v.front()` worked and also assigning auto it =  `*v.begin()` before hand worked well. And, sorry about all the problems in my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
   {
      auto it = *v.begin();
      if(it->left != NULL)
      {
          v.push_back(it->left);
      }
      if(it->right != NULL)
      {
          v.push_back(it->right);
      }
      v.erase(v.begin());
   }
```

Also with front

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
   {
       if(v.front()->left != NULL)
       {
          v.push_back(v.front()->left);
       }
       if(v.front()->right != NULL)
       {
          v.push_back(v.front()->right);
       }
       v.erase(v.begin());
   }
```